# Layout not properly updated after resizing

Tags: java, javafx, layout

Since `ScrollPane` doesn't allow e.g top-placed `ScrollBar` (and also few other reasons), I needed to create my own `ScrollBar` that I can position for my needs. Sadly - there are few problems originating mainly from maximizing and minimalizing screen (stage).

```
class SectionLeft extends HBox
{
    SectionLeft()
    {
        ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane();
        pane.setFitToWidth(true);
        HBox.setHgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        VBox content = new VBox(10);
        pane.setContent(content);

        pane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER); // hide normal bars.
        pane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);

        ScrollBar sb = new ScrollBar();
        sb.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        sb.minProperty().bind(pane.vminProperty());
        sb.maxProperty().bind(pane.vmaxProperty());
        sb.visibleAmountProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(content.heightProperty()));
        sb.managedProperty().bind(sb.visibleAmountProperty().lessThan(1.0));
        sb.visibleProperty().bind(sb.managedProperty());
        sb.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(pane.vvalueProperty());

        this.getChildren().addAll(pane, sb);
    }
}
```

Basically what we have here is a `HBox` that has 2 children - `ScrollPane` on left, and `ScrollBar` on right, where pane will expand to parent box and bar will only appear (and be managed at all) in box, when content exceeds pane's height.

Now - it all works fine, bar appears and goes as I resize content, but - when I would make something like:

Start program in small window (content fits, no bar needed) -> resize content (content exceeds small window, bar appears) -> maximalize window (since we have more height, content fits again, BUT - bars don't really disappear, or rather - are not updated as needed) - look image.

Other scenario:

Start program -> maximalize -> resize content so that it fits pane, but if I'd minimalize window, it wouldn't -> minimalize -> scroll bar will appear, but it will be placed incorectly (since layout was ran before bar's `managedProperty()` got update that parent should manage it).

[image]

So basically - when maximizing window, "managedProperty()" is ran too late for layout to get correct value, which then causes (now unmanaged) ScrollBar stay in layout (but become invisible, leaving empty space).

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why not use [`SplitPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html)?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson How is this related to scrolling?

Comment: Most of these types of problem arise due to people using `Layout Nodes` incorrectly. It's best to try to find a `Layout Node` that does most of the work for you. That's why I am suggesting that you try to implement your program using `SplitPane`.

Comment: You will have much better results if you use BorderPane instead of HBox and VBox.

Comment: @VGR That doesn't change anything. BorderPane works same as HBox here. While in BP I've center and right (or left/center), HBox is literally 2 children - content and scroll placed next to each other. The real problem lies in what I wrote after image in post - as to how managedProperty() of (any) node is being updated post-resize, thus leaving this "jump" between states where newly set value (false) doesn't apply to already calculated layout - which already happened while value was true and window was resized - I need a way to re-invoke that (requestLayout() and other methods doesn't work).